# Return the char value of null

Tags: c#, char, maxlength, letters-and-numbers

This my code;

```
public void Dönüştür()
{
    int TextboxLength = TextBox.MaxLength;
    string LowerText = TextBox.Text.ToLower();
    var AllCharacters = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < TextboxLength; i++)
    {
        char Characters = char.Parse(LowerText);
        switch (Characters)
        {
            case '0': AllCharacters += "0"; break;
            case '1': AllCharacters += "1"; break;
            case '2': AllCharacters += "2"; break;
            case '3': AllCharacters += "3"; break;
            case '4': AllCharacters += "4"; break;
            case '5': AllCharacters += "5"; break;
            case '6': AllCharacters += "6"; break;
            case '7': AllCharacters += "7"; break;
            case '8': AllCharacters += "8"; break;
            case '9': AllCharacters += "9"; break;

            case ' ': case '+': case '-': case '_': AllCharacters += "0"; break;
            case ':': case ';': case '=': case ',': case '.': AllCharacters += "1"; break;
            case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'ç': AllCharacters += "2"; break;
            case 'd': case 'e': case 'f': AllCharacters += "3"; break;
            case 'g': case 'ğ': case 'h': case 'ı': case 'i': AllCharacters += "4"; break;
            case 'j': case 'k': case 'l': AllCharacters += "5"; break;
            case 'm': case 'n': case 'o': case 'ö': AllCharacters += "6"; break;
            case 'p': case 'r': case 's': case 'ş': AllCharacters += "7"; break;
            case 't': case 'u': case 'ü': AllCharacters += "8"; break;
            case 'v': case 'y': case 'z': case 'x': case 'w': AllCharacters += "9"; break;
        }

    }
    MessageBox.Show(TextBox.MaxLength.ToString(), "TextBox MaxLength:");
    MessageBox.Show(AllCharacters.ToString(), "AllCharacters value:");
}
```

I want to convert the numbers to letters. The char value but it seems empty.

[image: AllCharacters]

If checked, the TextBox is filled, although for loop does not work. The reason for this may be the number of characters of 0 TextBox but the TextBox is filled.

[image: MaxLength]

What the problem is, where am I making mistake?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What is this site? I asked the question just wondering, I'm learning to be. That's not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping for the number of times specified by `TextBox.MaxLength`, which is zero, so it doesn't loop at all. Did you mean to loop by `TextBox.Text.Length`?

The `MaxLength` property, if set to more than zero, restricts the number of characters that may be entered into the textbox.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < TextBox.Text.Length; i++)
    {
         char Characters = LowerText[i];
         ...
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, I dont think this line`char Characters = char.Parse(LowerText);` does what you think it does. Instead try using a `foreach(char chVal in Textbox.Text)` loop